# Reading directories in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to read files from a directory in matlab. Then I need to check whether it is file or directory and then do processing. Can someone provide me a code snippet for that? or please suggest a link to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a look at the MathWorks site, they always have some nice examples and helpful remarks.
Eg:

[FileOperations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/managing-files.html)

Answer (score 4):

The function [DIR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) returns an array of structures, one for each element of the directory.  One of the structure members is a flag called `isdir`.

```
mydir = 'c:\test';
allentries = dir(mydir); % array of all files and dirs within target
diridxs = [allentries.isdir];
alldirs = allentries(diridxs); % array of all the dirs
allfiles = allentries(~diridxs); % array of all the files
for ctr = 1:length(allfiles)
    disp(allfiles(i).name)
```

Note that the directory entries include `.` and `..` which can be confusing when you're trying to recursively parse a directory tree...

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a blog that addresses at least part of your problem: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/08/02/processing-a-set-of-files/

--Loren